# Is fopen+fwrite quicker than shell_exec?

Tags: php, unix

I want to write text to a file (like log-entries/data/whatever), where the server is on a unix system

is it quicker to use:

```
$handle = fopen("somefile"); 
fwrite($handle,"sometext");
```

or this:

```
shell_exec("echo 'sometext' > somefile");
```

is there any other drawbacks to using the shell_exec method?
speed? security? preformance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something as simple as your example, neither will be noticeably faster and security is no issue.  If your shell arguments are to be PHP variables, then be sure to use `escapeshellcmd()` on them ([docs here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php)).

However, in procedural code, I think I would prefer the `fopen() fwrite()` method, just because it's easier to check for errors and the validity of your file handle before writing to it, and then check the return of `fwrite()` to make sure your write operation succeeded.  The shell command would only return a single error code, so it would be more difficult to debug where the error occurred.

Answer (score 3):

Way faster.  Just consider that shell_exec is forking, then loading a shell binary, running it, then the shell interprets the command, then the shell forks again to run the command ...

Answer (score 1):

The f...() functions would defnitely be faster/safer in the long run. Even though you're "only" doing an echo, the server still has to fork itself, exec() a shell, the shell has to parse its arguments, invoke echo, and then STILL open the file to write out your data via its own fopen/fwrite/fclose sequence.

For a simple bit of debugging, not a big deal. For writing out "frequent" log entries on a busy site, it'd be the death of your server.

Think of it as the difference between walking <--- to the fridge for a drink, or going ---> out the door and around the world, only to end up back at the fridge again.